# How can I get 2560X1080 resolution on my LG 29UM58 monitor, connected to a Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, displayport

I just bought the LG 29UM58 21:9. My computer is a Mac Mini late 2012 (i7 model) running OS X 10.11

The display preferences just shows 1920x1080 16:9 than then is stretched out to 2560x1080 21:9.

SwitchResX software doesn't work? (Crashes? Runs but doesn't offer other resolution choices?)

I use a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter.

How can I configure better resolution choices (ideally 2560 X 1080) for my setup?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a 1080 capable adapter or better. See this thread for some options.

- [How can a Mac mini drive 3440 pixels wide display instead of 1920?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217122/how-can-a-mac-mini-drive-3440-pixels-wide-display-instead-of-1920)

I'd get the [cable matters 4K adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K0UDJFI) over the 1080p one if you can afford the extra $4 cost.

Keep in mind HDMI spec as well for limits on resolution: [Can a MacBook Air support 2560x1600 output via HDMI using a Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to HMDI adaptor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84140/can-a-macbook-air-support-2560x1600-output-via-hdmi-using-a-mini-displayport-thu)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43796/discussion-on-answer-by-bmike-how-can-i-get-2560x1080-resolution-on-my-lg-29um58).